# How to load XML in to IE

Tags: .net, xml

Currently in Visual studio I am able to generate XML, but I want to open the result in IE.

The line of code marked with an arrow is the place where I generate the XML file, and I can see it in the XML visualizer when I right click on it. I want to open the XML in IE so that I can collapse and expand the nodes for ease of use. Can anyone please let me know how to view the XML in IE?

```
 public bool GenerateNETSXML(AccountPRC acct, User currentUser)
        {
            bool success = true;
            int nextTransactionSequence = 0;
            NetsXMLGen xmlGen = new NetsXMLGen();
       ---> string xml = xmlGen.GenerateNetsXml(acct, ref nextTransactionSequence); 
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] xmlBytes = encoding.GetBytes(xml);
            RiskXML riskxml = new RiskXML(true);
            riskxml.GeneratedDate = DateTime.Now;
            riskxml.TransactionSequence = nextTransactionSequence;
            riskxml.NetsXML = xmlBytes;
            acct.CurrentRisk.LoadRiskXMLs(false);
            acct.CurrentRisk.RiskXMLs.Add(riskxml);
            return success;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it to a file like so:

```
string s = "<xml><foo></foo></xml>";
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(s);
xdoc.Save("myfilename.xml");
```

Then open the file in IE like any other.